# rails 3 saving default image while uploading using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, image-upload

i use paperclip to upload images to the server in rails 3. If  the user didn't choose any file to upload i want to store a default image in the server i.e., storing a default image in different size like thumb, normal, feature...

**:default_url => '/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png'**

I already put the above line in the config/initialize folder.

But for my popup slider i use jAlert in that i use js(to read the image from the server) and db(to get the object id) to show the images. So if an id didn't have any image then no folder(thumb, normal,...) are created.

For that reason i want to store default image for id which didn't have image.

My basic need is to make image slider in a popup window.

Thanks,
Arivarasan L